# Without editor field item not saving

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to let a user create an object and save it to the database. I have scaffolded it all correctly etc and have modified my control to the following:

```
    Function Create(id As Integer) As ViewResult
        ViewBag.id = id
        Dim job As Job = New Job
        job.CustomerId = id
        job.JobAmount = 0
        job.JobDate = Date.Now()
        job.JobStatus = "Active"
        Return View(job)
    End Function
```

This then returns the following view:

```
        @ModelType Laundry.Job

        @Code
            ViewData("Title") = "Create"
        End Code

        <h2>Create</h2>

        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

        @Using Html.BeginForm()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(True)
            @<fieldset>
                <legend>Job</legend>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.JobDate)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.JobDate)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.JobDate)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.BillId)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.BillId)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.BillId)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.CustomerId)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.CustomerId)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.CustomerId)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.JobStatus)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.JobStatus)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.JobStatus)
                </div>

                <p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        End Using

        <div>
            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        </div>
```

I created a instance of job and passed it through the controller to the view in order to default certain values. Specifically I need to create a job object with the id passed to the controller but I do not want the user to be able to edit this id (they should not see this). I thought that if I simply deleted the following from my view:

```
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.CustomerId)
                </div>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.CustomerId)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.CustomerId)
                </div>
```

The object would still save with the customerId I set in my controller however it seems if I delete this code when it saves it saves the customerid as 0 and when its there it works correctly but the user can see and edit it.

Am I doing this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not want the user to be able to edit this id (they should not see this)

Use `@Html.HiddenFor(Function(model) model.CustomerId)` for this.  It will persist the value from view to controller, but not be visible to the user.